# exposing Mongodb from docker container on server

Tags: python, mongodb, docker, docker-compose

I have Nodejs+Mongodb webapp running inside two separate docker containers

I have 8080 for Nodejs and 27017 for Mongodb ports exposed in docker-compose.yml

I use pymongo to submit data from my python script
when I run it locally I am able to submit the data

But when I run it on company (internal) server I am not able to send data and I get mongodb access error(*port 27017: Connection refused*).

***dbOp.py***

```
self.read_db_config(fname)
self.dbname = user
url = 'mongodb://{0}:{1}/'.format(self.host,self.port)
print("url:{0}".format(url))

client = MongoClient(url)
db = client[self.dbname]
self.collection = db[self.coll]
if self.dbname in client.database_names():
    print("db exists::{0},{1}".format(self.dbname, client.database_names()))
    post = {"date": datetime.datetime.utcnow()}
    self.collection.insert_one(post)
else:
    print("creating db")
    post = {"date": datetime.datetime.utcnow()}
    self.collection.insert_one(post)
```

***docker-compose.yml***

```
version: "2"
services:
    web:
        build:
            context: .
            dockerfile: Dockerfile_node
        volumes: # Use this to mount app from local disk
            - ./:/usr/src/app
        ports:
            - "8080:8080"
            - "5858:5858"
        entrypoint: node --debug=5858 app.js
        links:
            - mongodb
    mongodb:
        image: mongo
        ports:
            - "27017:27017"
```

***Dockerfile_node***

```
FROM node:argon

# Create app directory
RUN mkdir -p /usr/src/app
WORKDIR /usr/src/app

# Install app dependencies
COPY package.json /usr/src/app/
RUN npm install

# Bundle app source
COPY . /usr/src/app

EXPOSE 8080
CMD [ "npm", "start" ]
```

Can someone suggest what could be missing.

Comment: MongoDB is work locally,  `Request > Local_PY_Redirector > MongoDB > Local_PY_Redirector > to_Client`

Comment: 1) locally==localhost. 2) PY_Script > PYMongo_Script (`url = 'mongodb://{0}:{1}/'.format(self.host,self.port)`) > Mongodb:27017. 3) Index.html > NodeJS>Mongodb works fine. So 2 is the culprit when self.host changes from localhost to  <server ip>

Comment: You mixed `CGI side`  and `local service` address. Create a local loop, can't call any mongodb scripts externally(got a lot security reason). Can call output not whole access database !  Only `localhost` allowed , otherwise can't block database injections.

Comment: Can you please elaborate, I am novice at this. Pretty much non tech when it comes to networking. CGI ?? I am not using any. I can read mongodb database from NodeJS which is exposed on 8080. I guess "links" in docker does the job of local loop. If you mean something else let me know. Or do you mean expose an API from NodeJS? (that is my last resort anyway :( )

Comment: Publish on 8080 and access from 5858 so you got a open port (listening all query). Which is internal or external query ? Use `pymongo` on python service and add a local `SYNC` trigger.

Comment: 5858 is used for debugging. Pymongo is what I was using. Anyway problem is resolved. It seems our company FireWall was blocking that port. Thanks for the help

Answer (score 1, accepted):

So the problem was Firewall. Opening port over there resolved the problem. Writing it here, in case some one else is stuck like me

Answer (score 0):

Not clear how do you call mongo from your web, but since you're running it in kind of docker-compose "network", your mongo have a hostname - 'mongodb'
So you should point your web to this, not localhost

Comment: yep that is what NodeJs does in my code and Pymongo needs explicit ip/hostname.